# IMPDP : How to import only Table data

Tags: oracle, import, impdp

I tried to import (TABLES, PROCEDURE, FUNCTION etc) from a dump file. I did a mistake by
executing `KILL -9 <PROCESS_ID>` while import was still going on.

So, I started to import again. Now, I did another mistake by NOT mentioning 
`TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE` . So, tables have been imported with duplicate records.

I want to get rid of duplicate data. There are more than 500 tables involved.
I am planning to import again by first truncating the table and then importing data only.

Below is the import command I have come up with. Will this command import ONLY table data(records) by first
truncating the table and then insert only the data?

```
impdp DIRECTORY=MY_DIRECTORY  dumpfile=EXP_MY_DUMP.dmp INCLUDE=TABLE_DATA TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=TRUNCATE
```

I could try executing myself and find out if that works. But, I have already tried twice and failed.

Also, I don't want to again import INDEX, SEQUENCES etc. Just table records.

Answer (score 0):

Remove INCLUDE=TABLE_DATA. That will not execute create table.. that should work.

Comment: How to exclude INDEX, Sequence re-creation?

Comment: I don't want to explicitly write so many excludes like `EXCLUDE=INDEX EXCLUDE=PROCEDURE EXCLUDE=SYNONYM EXCLUDE=GRANTS` etc. By including only TABLE, I want to say exclude all other objects.

Comment: In that case add INCLUDE= TABLE and not TABLE_DATA.

Comment: I tested with `INCLUDE= TABLE` . But, noticed that it is importing index, synonym, sequence and all other objects as well. And failed with error `ORA-31684: Object type .. already exists`

Comment: But, why did the command even pick the index, synonymn etc? By 'failure' , I meant to say it failed by trying to import objects other than Tables.